# How to fill a hole in face?

Tags: modeling, workflow

I have this bit of wall here:

[image]

As you can see, it is a window frame and I want the hole between the wall and the frame to be filled. I have searched it on youtube and so on but all I can find is tutorials for creating circular holes...

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no one set way to do this. It depends on what you are going for, what you are modeling or any special cases you are adhering to, etc.

In your case here, since you have basically two flat surfaces, you can add supporting edge loops to the outer mesh and join the matching edges together by selecting the edgeloops and manually filling each one with <kbd>F</kbd>, the images differ a bit but I think you get the point. *(Also, your flat outer mesh does not seem to need so many loops at the moment, you can remove some.)*

[image: Manually Filled]

In the example above you can also bridge the two edge loops by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> > *Bridge Edge Loops* after selecting the outer and inner edges to connect. **This only works when the amount of edges are equal in both loops**, but it will give a nice and cleaner result.

Or you can just select an edgeloop and use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to fill the gaps. *(I added an edgeloop to the middle of the frame in the image below before filling and aligned it accordingly with the other mesh so it stayed flat.)* You can do the same or use one of the existing ones depending on what you are going for.

[image: Fill Gaps Before]
[image: Fill Gaps After]

Comment: Thank you! That really helped me. I used the first suggestion you had. I also tried the one with the edgeloop-thing but I didn't got it to work. The window-frame did not become selected when I used edgeloop-select, just one side. Why is that?

Comment: @theva use `Shift` to select several times. After you use `Alt` and select the first edge loop or a part of it, hold `Shift` and do the same for the other(s) or you can select the edges or vertices one at a time.

Comment: When the split numbers match, you can use edit > edges > bridge two edge loops. First image in this answere could have been done with the bridge tool.

Comment: @RóbertLászlóPáli I know, I just wanted to make it explicitly applicable to OP's use case while showing that some of the geometry could be removed. Feel free to create an additional (more specific) answer.

Comment: @iKlsR "I just wanted to make it explicitly applicable ..." That is why I did not create another answer, just thought it is worth mentioning. :) Oh, and I was pretty sure that you knew about it.

Comment: @RóbertLászlóPáli, "Any time you feel you can make the post better, and are inclined to do so. [Editing](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/editing) is encouraged!"

Comment: Note, With 2.68 - selecting both loops and running the bridge tools works too, similar to fill with the advantage that you get quads and have some extra options (note, fixed a bug relating to this r58167)

Answer (score 3):

There is a very powerful and useful addon in blender called "Looptools" which can do this. To see a quick demo, [you can refer to this video.](http://youtu.be/Jnuj7BfTnVc?t=5m4s)

To know how to activate it, watch the video from the [beginning](http://youtu.be/Jnuj7BfTnVc) .

Comment: Can you add a small excerpt in the future on what exactly to do in OPs case. Link only answers aren't recommended as if the link goes, so does the answer.