# Subdivision Surface Artifact with Creases

Tags: modeling, topology, subdivision-surface

I'm currently in the process of modeling the nose section of an aircraft. I started by creating the outlines of the cockpit windows, which need to be straight so I creased them. Then I connected this outline with cross-sections of the fuselage. To obtain the rounded shape of the fuselage I added the Subdivision Surface Modifier. This is where I ran into a problem. I cannot get rid of the artifact shown in the picture below.

[image]

I tried to add more support loops and played around with the crease settings. It looks like due to the Subdivision Surface Modifier the mesh gets bent in a weird way. I suspect this could be a topology issue.

[image]

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this artifact and/or give me a pointer on how to improve my overall topology? Thank you in advance for your help.

EDIT: Added .blend file

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2135/subdivision-surface-giving-strange-geometry-with-tris/2136#2136 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/123617/how-to-avoid-pinching-on-concave-shapes-with-the-bevel-modifier-and-subsurf

Comment: thanks for the answers, I checked the normals, they look fine to me. I also edited my original post to include the .blend file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your geometry is not exactly flat. If you look at it from the top, you will see this.

I suggest moving your vertices like this:

[image]

But your main problem is that the creases end inside the mesh. If you extend them all the way to the end of your mesh, it will be without artifacts. Like this.

[image]

You can also clear the crease and insert two edge loops. I find it slightly easier to control the exact bevel this way. Use <kbd>ctrl + R</kbd> to create a edge loop. Click on the faces where you want it. Slide it up where you want it. Left click to finish placement.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! That solved the issue. I will definitely try your suggestion with the two edge loops.