# How can i cover a space between a path i drew?

Tags: path

[image]

Hi, im a trully beginner in blender. I made this logo and now i need to fill that empty space between the path i used to draw the logo. Fill it or cover the top and bottom with some kind of "surface" but i have no idea how. Any suggestions ?[image]

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/136/how-can-i-convert-an-svg-to-a-mesh/ and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18177/how-fill-face-between-irregular-curves or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43287/how-do-i-add-polygons-to-fill-a-face and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1754/how-to-fill-a-hole-in-face

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into the curve settings and choose 2D.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hi go in edit mode and go into edge select. While holding shift, select all the top and bottom edges on the Nike logo and press F (stands for fill) there you go.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The thing is, the Nike logo is made with the path option like so it has no edges and when i try to press F to fill it, a message appears saying "Cannot make segment". Im gonna had a new picture in the question so you can see.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know about that. I don't use the path tool that much.

Comment: No Problem. Hope you figure it out soon. (:

Comment: Looks like you got it.