# More Control Over Face Creation

Tags: faces

I have a model that I hollowed out and now want to give it an open top. I would like to just have Blender create a face like shown in the picture, but instead it fills the whole thing with a face. How can I change this?

Side view of image https://i.stack.imgur.com/KN0Ry.png

Top View (red is what I want to be filled in): https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSWzq.png

What happens when I fill in a face https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EPvd.png

Thanks!

Comment: bridge edge loops will do this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fill a hole in face?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1754/how-to-fill-a-hole-in-face)

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: Yes, that answers my question. Thank you. I won't edit my original question since the other question explains it thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit more searching I found that using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> *> Bridge Edge Loops* after selecting both the inner and outer rings was what I was looking for. Link if you need it: [How to fill a hole in face?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1754/how-to-fill-a-hole-in-face)